# Google spreadsheet into email

Tags: google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet to track clients contact information. For convenience, I entered their email addresses as a hyperlink. When I click on the link, a blank 'untitled' page opens. I'm not sure why it is not opening up in Google Mail and attaching itself into a new email.

It's been suggested since my computer also has some Microsoft apps on it there is an interference being created between the two.

Is there a change I can make in the settings to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:labnol@ctrlq.org", "Send Email")
```